# MDX - Get value from last day of previous year

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have the following table, and I need to achieve the value of last day of previous year on every row (3rd column). For example, for date 25/02/2020 we need the value of 31/12/2019.

Is it possible to do it with MDX?

```
| Date | Value | PrevYearLastDay |

| 2019-12-31 | 100 | - |

| 2020-01-01 | 110 | 100 |

| 2020-02-01 | 120 | 100 |

| 2020-03-01 | 130 | 100 |
```

Comment: Its difficult understanding what you are looking for. Kindly add a screen shot of how the result should look like in excel and what are the dimensions and measures in your cube.

Comment: Hi MoazRub, I need to achieve the PrevYearLastDay colum.